# How to stop double printing using System.out.println() in an if/if else statement?

Tags: java

I'm fairly new to programming and learning Java as part of an online course.

I've been given many different coding exercises, one of which should be relatively simple where I print out two statements ("Sorry, try again" or "Win!") depending on if the two different numbers of 6 sided die match.

The problem is for whatever reason both statements are printed even though only one should appear (either two "Sorry, try again"s or "Sorry, try again" followed by "Win!" if the numbers matched, I've attached a screenshot with details.

Any idea why this is happening? Code below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class DiceRoll extends JPanel
{
    private int firstDice;      // to hold the value for the first dice
    private int secondDice;     // to hold the value for the second dice
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        firstDice  = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1; // get a value for the first dice
        secondDice = (int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1; //get a value for the second dice
        // draw the dice squares
        g.setColor(Color.blue);
        g.fillRect(20, 20, 60, 60);
        g.setColor(Color.magenta);
        g.fillRect(120, 20, 60, 60);
        // put the values on the dice
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawString(" " + firstDice, 43, 54);
        g.drawString(" " + secondDice, 143, 54);
        // write the values under the dice
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString("First dice = " + firstDice, 20, 100); 
        g.drawString("Second Dice = " + secondDice, 120, 100); // print out the dice values
        
        
        
        if (firstDice != secondDice) 
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, try again");
        }
        else if (firstDice == secondDice) 
        {
            System.out.println("Win!");
        }
   }
}
```

I've looked up solutions online and according to what I've read it should be correct. Feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: Java and Javascript are two comlpetely different things. Please take care when tagging your questions

Comment: This code gets executed every time the component is repainted

Comment: It sounds like you're assuming that the `if` structure is somehow broken in Java, though it seems *far* more likely that `paintComponent()` is being invoked more than once.

Comment: You don't need the `==` comparison after the `!=` comparison. If `!=` is false, then of necessity `==` will be true, so you just need a plain `else`.

Comment: @David I think that might be the problem, I don't really know how to fix it though, the paintComponent() needs to be invoked twice in order to draw a graphic of both die. Any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: why twice tho? wouldnt once work fine?

Comment: Since paintComponent is called when needed, don't expect your  print's to be reliable.

Comment: @GrindingForReputation To be honest I'm not sure, most of the code isn't mine, only the if/else if segment near the bottom is. The exercise doesn't mention anything about changing the existing code, only adding my own for the println() statements. That's why I'm so confused about why its printing/invoking twice. I'm really new to coding so it doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Can you include slightly more code so I can at least give you an idea on how to implement something?

Comment: @GrindingForReputation I'm afraid the code I included in the original post is all of it, there's nothing else to include. Sorry to be a bother. Just to be clear, the print statements occur twice one after another

Comment: Its completely fine dw! I'll see if I can come up with anything :D

Comment: If this code has been given by an online Java course you should search for a different online course. Whoever wrote this code should not teach other people Java programming. As said by others, the state of a program should not be changed in the `paintComponent` method and a program solely consisting of a `paintComponent` method does not do anything useful. Further, `(int) (Math.random() * 6) + 1` is not a recommended way of creating a random integer number.

Comment: @Holger yea especially considering you're painting 2 dice which require the paint method to be run twice.

Comment: @Holger That's damning! I've had some issues with this course before but this is the first time I've been completely lost as to what I'm doing wrong!

Comment: @Dylanduran for the time being maybe create a temporary int, if the value is 0 print the lines and increment the variable, if the value is 1 ignore it. That's all I could think of with this code. It get's the job done (i hope)

Comment: But there must be code creating a `DiceRoll` object and displaying it somewhere as otherwise you wouldn’t notice the problem of repeated execution of the `if`/print statement.

Comment: @Holger exactly i asked for more code to decide onto something, but apparently all the code has been included in the original post. [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77475135/how-to-stop-double-printing-using-system-out-println-in-an-if-if-else-statemen?noredirect=1#comment136584950_77475135)

Comment: @Holger I'm a complete moron. Can't blame the course for this one! Turns out what I'd down is I'd somehow not seen the *second* batch of code that was in a separate file that called the code I'd linked above. All I had to do was add a new public void method and call that in the second file. Thanks for pointing out about the creation of the DiceRoll object, I genuinely have no idea how I could've missed something so obvious. It works like a charm now!

Comment: @GrindingForReputation Thanks for your help too, I was being a complete idiot if you take a look at my reply to Holger. It works absolutely fine now that I've grown a pair of eyes

Comment: @Dylanduran its ok just be more careful next time (and also thats basically what i meant by more code :D)

Comment: That doesn’t change the fact that the dice rolls should not happen in the `paintComponent` method and if that’s been given by the course, it’s teaching wrong things. As said, the `paintComponent` method will be invoked by the system whenever a refresh is needed (try dragging another window or an icon over the component), outside the program’s control.

Comment: @Holger Maybe not, its a degree level course as well so if the code looks sketchy to people on here that isn't a good sign.

Answer (score 0):

Dice rolls action should not be in `paintComponent` method because you can't control how this `paintComponent` be invoked by system. Put dice roll in the `main()` and try again.